# Wpbakery post grid autoplay does not work

Tags: css, wordpress, wpbakery

https://shorturl.at/sESTX

I want to create two blocks: one that shows the last three blog posts previews, then the previous three and so on, in an autoplay playback. It is called on the page as “Nuestro blog”. The other block is similar, but with testimonials, and showing only one testimonial per page (“Testimonios” block). In addition, it should let the user paginate manually, using arrows.

If I create a Post grid with pagination and autoplay with infinite loop it doesn't work. It's strange: it only works with the first step: both in "Our blog" and in the "Testimonials" block it loads the next three blog previews or the next testimonial, but after that it freezes, no matter what browser I use.

I use Wordpress Ver. 5.8.7 and WPBakery Page Builder ver. 6.7.0

I'm not considering upgrading, not at least at the moment. There are some plugins that I really need that don't work in the new wordpress versions.

I have tried to deactivate all plugins and change the theme with no results.

Also, it would be great to use some CSS tricks to manipulate the arrow that lets the user paginate. What I want is to make it always visible with no added transparency, no matter if the user hovers over the block, and with a custom color, not black.

Thank you very much in advance.